# Get image height and width into Data size PHP

Tags: php, image, height, width

I am using this code in my webpage. I use Data-size attribute for maintaining the aspect ratio of the image while pop-up.

```
<figure>
          <a href="img/large-image/1.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl"  data-size="1024x1024">
              <img src="img/small-thumbnail/1.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
          </a>
          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
<figure>
          <a href="img/large-image/2.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="964x1024">
              <img src="img/small-thumbnail/2.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
          </a>
          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 2</figcaption>
        </figure>

<figure>
          <a href="img/large-image/3.jpg" data-size="683x683">
              <img src="img/small-thumbnail/3.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
          </a>
          <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption 3</figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Now I can't enter every time the image dimensions manually. so, How can I   automatically put the image width and height  value  into the "data-size" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getimagesize()` can be used for getting image dimensions:

```
<?php
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("img/large-image/1.jpg");
?>

<a href="img/large-image/1.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl"  data-size="<?php echo $width . 'x' . $height; ?>">
```

Comment: it is not working yet. it's showing me "list($width, $height) = getimagesize("img/large-image/1.jpg");" on the page

Comment: still it is not working. when I click on a small thumbnail, it disappears the large image and the function should not work properly.

Comment: index1.php file in zip files contains `<a href="img/large-image/1.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl"  data-size="<?php echo $width . 'x' . height; ?>">` You have missed `$` in variable height.